# Can't find variable: ReactPropTypes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-props, prop

Hello i'm trying setup an old code react native version>0.57. Whenever i'm trying to run i'm getting this error Can't find variable: ReactPropTypes. i checked the whole code everywhere even i checked the node module nothing is wrong present i don't known what to do now. This is 
 my package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-3d-model-view": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.6.4",
    "react-native-customisable-switch": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-image-marker": "^0.3.9",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-imagepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-location": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-pdf": "^5.0.11",
    "react-native-pdf-view": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-picker-dropdown": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-share": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-stripe": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-stripe-api": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-zip-archive": "^3.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-notification-badge": "^1.4.0",
    "react-viro": "^2.7.3",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "three": "^0.100.0",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.2.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.2"
  },
```

Any help will be appreciated. i'm running this in android.

Comment: try to run below command react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res and then react-native run-android

Comment: no same issue.............

Comment: even i reaplaced this import React, {Component} from 'react'; with this import React from 'react' in my js files.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because in your code somewhere you might have used `React Proptypes`.

This is particularly a type checking library where you can define about the type casted variables which you pass as props whether they need to be in string or a integer or a array or a function etc. Try importing it in the page where you used but before that install the library. Prop type is used for strict coding structure.

Try the steps [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) to install the library.